# Eliminating rows with duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table like this:

```
Number      | Number 1     | Date     | Date 1
------------+--------------+----------+----------
1...........| 1000.........| 5........| 10........
2...........| 1000.........| 7........| 10........
1...........| 1001.........| 5........| 11........
2...........| 1001.........| 7........| 11........
8...........| 2000.........| 18.......| 20........
9...........| 2000.........| 19.......| 20........
```

I want to remove duplicate values in both column `Number` and `Number 1` while keeping the difference between `Date` and `Date 1` minimum. For example, for the 2 rows where `Number 1` is 2000, I delete the row where `Number` is 8 and keep the row where `Number` is 9 since 19 is closer to 20 than 18.

But I am stuck when trying to remove duplicate values in the first 4 rows of the table. If I use the above method, I would delete all rows where `Number` is 1 since the difference between `Date` and `Date 1` in these rows is larger than that where `Number` is 2. This pattern occurs many times in my table so I cannot manually delete duplicate values.

Comment: Can you provide the desired result, as if it was a SELECT rather than a DELETE? And what is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

The following gets information about the rows you want to *keep*:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.date1
        from table t2
        where t.number1 = t2.number1
        order by abs(t2.date1 - t2.date)
        limit 1
       ) as date1
from table t;
```

You can incorporate this into a `delete` using `join`:

```
delete t
    from table t left join
         (select t.*,
                 (select t2.date1
                  from table t2
                  where t.number1 = t2.number1
                  order by abs(t2.date1 - t2.date)
                  limit 1
                 ) as date1
          from table t
         ) tt
         on tt.number1 = t.number1 and tt.date1 = t.date
    where tt.number1 is null;
```